# header doesn't stays not on top weird glitch

Tags: html, css, header

I need help with the header that doesn't stays in the right spot when the browser size gets smalles

http://eerlijkmbo.nl/

css:

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    max-width:420px;
    height:160px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.8s ease;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? In Google Chrome it remains the same full screen than smaller.

Comment: It's perfect for me on fox

Comment: Internet explorer moves it. Try to erase width: 100%; and make it fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can just erase the max-width to make it not fluid. Then insert it in a div like #headerContainer and make it width: 420px;